# Is it possible to redirect user from jquery loaded php file?

Tags: php, jquery, header, load

I want the user to be redirected when a php file is loaded through `jquery`

Example

```
$(form).submit(function(){
event.preventDefault();
    $("#div").load("phpfile.php");
});
```

The `PHP` file contains: `header('Location: ...');`

but when the php file is loaded,nothing comes up when I add the header there... Otherwise the result is ok and is loaded to the assigned div. Is there any possible way to redirect user from loaded php file? Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use windows.location.href ? any programming reason ?

Comment: Why don't you just submit form using default process instead of ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl - Because the user is able and supposed to click the form multiple times, so to make it faster I want to process the form submission without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Then question is confusing since you are asking how to do redirect

Comment: @charlietfl -  Yes, the php file contains the form submission, + the "if" statement, and when the "if" returns true, the user must be redirected.

Comment: An AJAX response doesn't do redirects.  Since AJAX and page refreshes are fundamentally opposite things.  If you want to use AJAX for this then the redirect would happen client-side, not server-side.

Comment: @David - So obviously, as you said, it is not possible to redirect user from a loaded php file ...?

Comment: @StevenDropper: The browser will ignore that redirect when it comes in an AJAX response.  Your client-side code would have to look for the redirect in the response and redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: @David - How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need conditional redirect I would suggest you return a json response:

The various responses would look something like:

```
{"redirect":false, "html":"success message html", "url": ""}
// OR
{"redirect":true, "html":"", "url": "/new/url"}
```

Then use `$.getJSON` instead of `load()`

```
$.getJSON('phpfile.php', function(response){
     if(response.redirect){
        window.location = response.url;
      }else{
        $('#div').html(response.html);
      }
}).fail(function(){ alert('Ooops we got a problem'); });
```

Comment: {"redirect":false, "html":"success message html", "url": ""} = Is a Php code?
*Stupid question*.. o/o

Comment: No ... it is json that php would generate and echo as response

Comment: Then it means I'd have to implement a json format, and I have never met with a json so no idea what to where